# What VM control panels support snapshots?

Tags: virtualization, snapshot

Which web based control panels provide snapshots?

- Please include free software and paid software < $1000.
- If you can, be specific as to if it supports:

  - VMWare
  - Xen
  - Virtuozzzo
  - OpenVZ
  - Other
- Please also try to be specific about the type of snapshots:

  - True Snapshot (near-instant point-in-time block-level diff)
  - Full Snapshot (stand-alone backup)
  - Other

Answer (score 0):

RHEV - works with KVM - http://www.redhat.com/virtualization/rhev/server/